# parse image and display in uiimageview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, nsxmlparser

I have developed an application that fetches the feed from a sever, displays the list of feed and on selection of a particular feed, options for sharing to twitter or Facebook is displayed. On selecting one social network, user is able to upload that.

Until this it is fine.

But now I am stuck with an issue. The php i am parsing to fetch the feed has links for some images. I want to take the first five images from the php and display in UIImageView. This also should be auto-updated as and when the new contents are uploaded.

Please let me know how can I do it.

Since, I have a bit of urgency, a demo code will be very useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you are getting url of your image from php.

```
NSURL *url             = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.abc.com/photo.jpg"];
NSData *data           = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image         = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

This will populate your `imageView`. If you receive any updates from backend, repeat this piece of code & you should be good...

If you want some image caching too the as Shubhank suggests [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is a good option.

Comment: I did this, but I can't set the url statically. I need top five image urls

Answer (score 0):

If you have links of images..then just use this git

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

So steps are :

- Make a ImageView
- Set it image using the API method(above git )..
- The image will be downloaded in background and will automatically
  update..